# how to check if certain values are repeated at the same time?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, object, key-value

I have an array of values like the one in the example, which I'm going through in a for loop to set certain conditions, but I get to a point where I don't know how to check for repeating values

```
const objectsData:[
 a:{boxTop = 320,
   boxLeft = 1750,
   boxHeigth = 245,
   boxWidth = 310
 },
 b:{boxTop = 20,
   boxLeft = 580,
   boxHeigth = 245,
   boxWidth = 310
 },
 c:{boxTop = 320,
   boxLeft = 1750,
   boxHeigth = 245,
   boxWidth = 310
 },
 d:{boxTop = 320,
   boxLeft = 1750,
   boxHeigth = 245,
   boxWidth = 310
 },
 e:{boxTop = 136,
   boxLeft = 10,
   boxHeigth = 245,
   boxWidth = 310
 },
]
```

taking this object array I need to check which of the objects repeat the values "boxLeft" and "boxTop"  at the same time (in the example would be objects "a", "d" and "c") to modify them adding a value that would increase in case there are more than two objects that repeat values.

any idea is welcome.
Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) We need some logic (function) to get the "comparison value" of each object. For example, given the object `a: { boxTop: 320, boxLeft: 1750, boxHeigth: 245, boxWidth: 310 }`, as input, we want the value (string) `'{"boxTop":320,"boxLeft":1750}'` as output, and then we can use that string to compare to other values.

2) Given a value, for example the string `'{"boxTop":320,"boxLeft":1750}'`, we need some logic to count how many times that value appeared in some collection (like a list, dictionary for example). There are many ways to approach that problem, I decided to use a dictionary where the `key` represents some value and the `value` of the dictionary represents how many times that key appeared in the collection.

Here's a JavaScript (node) implementation of that since you have javascript in your name:

```js
const objectsData = {
    a: { boxTop: 320, boxLeft: 1750, boxHeigth: 245, boxWidth: 310 },
    b: { boxTop: 20, boxLeft: 580, boxHeigth: 245, boxWidth: 310 },
    c: { boxTop: 320, boxLeft: 1750, boxHeigth: 245, boxWidth: 310 },
    d: { boxTop: 320, boxLeft: 1750, boxHeigth: 245, boxWidth: 310 },
    e: { boxTop: 136, boxLeft: 10, boxHeigth: 245, boxWidth: 310 },
};

function getBoxLeftAndBoxTop(obj) {
    const { boxTop, boxLeft } = obj;
    return JSON.stringify({ boxTop, boxLeft });
}

const counterBoxLeftAndBoxTop = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(objectsData)) {
    const box = getBoxLeftAndBoxTop(objectsData[key]);
    const currentCount = counterBoxLeftAndBoxTop[box];
    counterBoxLeftAndBoxTop[box] = currentCount ? currentCount + 1 : 1;
}

console.log(counterBoxLeftAndBoxTop);
/* Outputs:
    {
      '{"boxTop":320,"boxLeft":1750}': 3,
      '{"boxTop":20,"boxLeft":580}': 1,
      '{"boxTop":136,"boxLeft":10}': 1
    }
    */

console.log(`Objects that appears 2 or more times: `);
for (const key of Object.keys(objectsData)) {
    const box = getBoxLeftAndBoxTop(objectsData[key]);
    const currentCount = counterBoxLeftAndBoxTop[box];
    if (currentCount >= 2) {
        console.log(key);
    }
}
/* Outputs:
    Objects that appears 2 or more times:
    a
    c
    d
    */
```